# How to authenticate an end user with OAuth 2.0 for BigQuery API with python as a backend code in cloud function

Tags: python, authentication, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, authorization

We have created a Flutter Web app that fetches bigquery data through bigquery API from Cloud Function. We were using a service account for authentication but as we want to make our application public, we need to use `OAuth` for end-user and use `OAuth` credentials.

I have tried to deploy the code from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed) for testing on cloud function but the cloud function keeps on running and shuts down because of timeout. I then checked the logs and found that, the reason was the cloud function doesn't allow the browser to open for authentication as it would do when run locally.

Logs:

- Function execution started

---

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2   /auth?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&state=IXYIkeZUTaisTMGUGkVbgnohlor7Jx&access_type=offline.
```

---

- Function execution took 180003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

I am confused as to how can I now authenticate and authorize a user once and have that credentials for every other bigquery API used in our web app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of the use of Cloud Functions. The documentation you shared clearly states:

> This guide explains how to authenticate by using user accounts for access to the BigQuery API when your app is installed onto users' machines.

This is never the case for a Cloud Function, since it is hosted in a Google Cloud Server and available for you to use via an HTTP request or a background process.

Because of that, Cloud Function will interact with other GCP products by using Service Accounts and if you want to setup authentication you will have to set it up in the Cloud Function layer, for which I recommend you to take a look at [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) which explains the principles of authentication with Cloud Functions